# Hide a view when a dependent view is hidden in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible in ContraintLayout to hide/show a view when a dependent view is gone/visible?
Obviously it's possible by using CoordinatorLayout with a custom behavior or by using an wrapped layout, however the mentioned approaches involve additional layouts. I would like to see such an approach that doesn't introduce additional layouts

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to group the views together using the new "group" feature of `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.x. See [this posting](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/whats-new-in-constraint-layout-1-1-x-f0bdd4dbdfb3#016b) on Medium.

> Groups, like the Guidelines, are widgets with size 0. But Group helps to apply some action to a set of widgets. The most common case, is to control a visibility of a collection of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically.

When you set the vivisiblity of a compounant in your code, change the visibility value of the dependent view.